# Should I use a Class or a function for getting a instance of a class?

Tags: function, kotlin, class, inheritance

```
fun main() {
    println(A(1).i)
    println(B(1).i)
}
                               
open class A(val i: Int)
                              
class B(val j: Int) : A(10+j)
```

Should I use a class like `B` or `fun B(j: Int) = A(10+j)`?

Comment: Depends what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: Im using an Api(Bukkit) and i want a custom permission with name parameter and a default prefix. And theres already a Permission(name: String) class. So now im using:
fun PluginPermission(string: String): Permission {
    return Permission("$PLUGIN_PERMISSION_PREFIX.$string")
}

Comment: That sounds like it should be a function, not a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you're trying to do. In your case (Bukkit API) it's better to use the class since it gives your PluginPermission class as same methods as in base Permission class, but if you don't need so much flexibility then feel free to use the builder function as you do now

Comment: I have the same methods as in the base Permission already using a function, cuz it just returns the base Permisison class

Comment: @friedFat okay, then choice is up to you. I prefer flexibility, so I recommend classes, but everything is in your hands